# Avoid quoting in CMake add_custom_command

Tags: cmake, quotes

I'm trying to create a simple batcher, which runs a script over a set of files.

So, after globbed files, I've created the following custom command to execute the script:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${RESOURCE_GFX} COMMAND ${EXE_GFX_EXPORT} ${GFX_EXPORT_PARAMETERS} ${RESOURCE_SWF})
```

where `EXE_GFX_EXPORT` is the script program, something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Scaleform\GFx SDK 3.1\Bin\gfxexport.exe`; `RESOURCE_SWF` is the file that the script runs on; and `GFX_EXPORT_PARAMETERS` are script's parameters, something in the form of `-i DDS -share_images -qp`.

CMake "translates" this custom command in:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Scaleform\GFx SDK 3.1\Bin\gfxexport.exe" "-i DDS -share_images -qp" "C:\path\to\file.swf"
```

but `gfxexport.exe` can't handle parameters surrounded by double quotes. Is there a way to avoid CMake automatically puts them around `GFX_EXPORT_PARAMETERS` variable?

Thanks guys,
Raffaele.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the [separate_arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/separate_arguments.html) function on the parameter `GFX_EXPORT_PARAMETERS` before invoking `add_custom_command`:

```
separate_arguments(GFX_EXPORT_PARAMETERS_LIST WINDOWS_COMMAND "${GFX_EXPORT_PARAMETERS}")
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${RESOURCE_GFX} COMMAND ${EXE_GFX_EXPORT} ${GFX_EXPORT_PARAMETERS_LIST} ${RESOURCE_SWF})
```